# Performing an action when clicking on a select option, but with unknown id

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twig

i'm facing a big problem with jquery, wordpress and twig here.

My aim is to display a predefined select when the user selects an option from a select. The problem is that i don't know a way to check which option he has selected, because i can't get the option value with wp_dropdown_categories. Even harder makes it the twig engine, which doesn't allow me to use every php function.

I solved the problem already with this code:

```
jQuery("#property_contract_haupt option:eq( {{ foo-1 }} )").click(function () {
                            {% for i in 0..10 %}
                            jQuery('#property_contract_no{{ i }}').hide();
                            jQuery('#input{{ i }}').hide();
                            {% endfor %}
                            jQuery('#property_contract_no{{ foo }}').show();

                            <!-- show an input if there is one for the number of foo -->
                            jQuery('#input{{ foo }}').show();
                    });
```

But unfortunately that solution doesn't work in Chrome or Safari, because click doesn't seem to be legal on options. I already read a lot of threads about that problem and found out that i need to use the on change event, but i can't identify the selected option then because i can't get the value of the options.

I would be nice if you could help me finding a solution for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

use the code below:

```
jQuery("#property_contract_haupt").on("change", function(){
    if(jQuery(this).value === "the desired option value attribute"){
        // do my desired action
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but the content isn't static, i read categories with wp_dropdown_categories which makes it impossible to check for the value of the options.

Comment: I see that in your code u're relying on index of the options, for that you can use: $(this).prop('selectedIndex'): inside the change event instead of $(this).value()

Comment: Thank you, that helped me! I'm happy i got that problem off the table, thanks to you